# MongoDb Aggregation $count to display 0

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collections with `7` Subjects.

`6` Subjects with credit value of `3`

`1` Subject with credit value of `6`.

I have to find the total number of subjects that have credit value of more than `6`.

How to i make it print `0`?

```
db.Subject.aggregate([{$match:{"subject.prerequisite":{$gt:6}}},
                      {$count:"Total"}])
```

Expected: `Total : 0`

Actual: `Nothing`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your `$match` returns no documents MongoDB simply stops processing further pipeline stages which is a bit counterintuitive in this case since you expect `$count` to always return the number of documents, even if it's `0`.

If you want to get `total` value anyway you can take advantage of [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) operator, try:

```
db.Subject.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            matched: [ {$match:{"subject.prerequisite":{$gt:6}}} ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Total: { $size: "$matched" }
        }
    }
])
```